# Проект в Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio

Начал делать проект в Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 и что-то нажал, после чего папки видны, а файлы нет, что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правой кнопкой мыши нажмите на папку -> Добавить -> Существующий элемент ... -> Выбираете файл -> Нажимаете кнопку "Добавить".

Answer (score 1):

В Solution Explorer сверху кнопка[image]